# Display different Divs depending on PHP Condition

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm looking to display a particular div which contains a form button, and 3 links if a custom field is completed, and a different div without a form button and 3 links if the custom field is not completed.

I've tried looking up how to use the  commands properly, but I'm not having much luck.

I would like this to appear if the custom field "add_to_cart" IS completed:

```
<div class="purchase">
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'add_to_cart', true)); ?><?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('itunes_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('itunes_url'); ?>">iTunes</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('amazon_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('amazon_url'); ?>">Amazon</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('cd_baby_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('cd_baby_url'); ?>">CD Baby</a></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

And this to appear if the custom field is not completed:

```
<div class="purchase2">
<?php if (get_field('itunes_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('itunes_url'); ?>">iTunes</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('amazon_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('amazon_url'); ?>">Amazon</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('cd_baby_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('cd_baby_url'); ?>">CD Baby</a></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

For the first part, I know I need to use:

```
<?php if (get_field('add_to_cart') != ""): ?>
```

But it is just the ELSE part that I'm stuck at.. I keep getting parse errors, and I really don't know all that much about PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example :

```
<?php if (true) : ?>

// If part here 

<?php else : ?>

// Else part here

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is called the alternative syntax http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?php if (get_field('add_to_cart') != ""): ?>
<div class="purchase">
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'add_to_cart', true)); ?>
<?php if (get_field('itunes_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('itunes_url'); ?>">iTunes</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('amazon_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('amazon_url'); ?>">Amazon</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('cd_baby_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('cd_baby_url'); ?>">CD Baby</a><?php endif;?>
</div>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="purchase2">
<?php if (get_field('itunes_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('itunes_url'); ?>">iTunes</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('amazon_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('amazon_url'); ?>">Amazon</a> |<?php endif;?>
<?php if (get_field('cd_baby_url') != ""): ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('cd_baby_url'); ?>">CD Baby</a><?php endif;?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble getting it to work though. Would it be possible for you to show me how this would work with the code I included above? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/electric/public_html/test/nadine/wp-content/themes/nadine2013/archive-na_musicreleases.php on line 45